# BigQuery - Extract substring from column

Tags: google-bigquery, split, substring, regexp-substr

I have column let's say called "assets" with results looks like this

//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/ABC/datasets/123

//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/BlaBla-something/datasets/12345

//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/ProjectName/datasets/6789

I want to case to another column only part of text from first column :  after "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/"  and don't want to have this part /datasets/123 so in results I want only text in between and new column with name "asset_code" like this :

`**Result **`

`| assets                                                           | asset_code        | |//bigquery.is.com/projects/ABC/datasets/123                        |ABC                | |//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/BlaBla-something/datasets/12345 |BlaBla-something   | |//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/ProjectName/datasets/6789       |ProjectName        |`

Would you be able to advice ?

`tried substr.   REGEXP_EXTRACT but got stucked split`

Comment: if I understood correctly assest_code you only want  ABC not the entire ABC/datasets/123 is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below approach

```
select assets, 
  regexp_extract(assets, r'//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/(.*?)/') as asset_code
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you see the 3 examples you mentioned. The code is always in the 3rd position you can just use split function  you dont need to use REGEXP_EXTRACT to get the values. Below is the sql code

```
select SPLIT(REPLACE('//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/ProjectName/datasets/6789', '//', ''),'/')[OFFSET(2)] as assest_code
```

This is sql code which works with the columns

```
select assets, SPLIT(REPLACE(assets, '//', ''),'/')[OFFSET(2)] as assest_code from table
```

Comment: it works, thank you.